# Retrieve logged on Windows User (ActiveDir) in JSF2 Application (Glassfish)

Tags: jakarta-ee, active-directory, glassfish, single-sign-on

i'm currently having trouble on finding out what the state-of-the-art/standard-solution for getting the login-name of the currently signed on user in my application. By login, i mean the (Windows)-Username logged on on the client that is using the applciation. It will run only in an intranet environment.

I'm using a Windows Server Environment, using Glassfish for deploying my JSF2-Application.

What i found so far are suggestions regarding WAFFLE, jCIFS and SPNEGO. All i could find out about WAFFLE and Glassfish seems to be either [out of date](https://groups.google.com/forum/?fromgroups=#!topic/waffle-users/5ZOCPccvNTI), or [can't be found anymore](https://github.com/dblock/waffle/blob/master/Source/JNAWindowsAuthProvider/src-test/waffle/servlet/NegotiateSecurityFilterTests.java). Did i just search wrong or are there really no "tutorials" how to configure WAFFLE for use with Glassfish? jCIFS, as far as i read isn't supported anymore. SPNEGO has a tutorial for Glassfish, but to be honest, i couldn't follow it and wasn't able to reporduce all the steps. Obviously, some background knowledge on authentication mechanisms - which i don't have - would be helpful.

So now i'm hoping, since most information i found about this topic is at least 1,5 years old, that since then something new has come up to solve my problem. If not, then what would be your suggestions? Since i've written some PHP-Apps (Running on Apache) before where i was able to get the username by the REMOTE_USER server-variable i thought about calling my JSF-App through Apache and passing the username that way. Could that also be an option? Of course, if i had the choice, i would prefer a JavaEE-Solution...

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

To get the currently logged in user:

```
System.getProperty("user.name");
```

Comment: I need the user of the client machine, not the account the glassfish instance is running on my server, whom this seems to return

Answer (score 0):

For Java EE, get the logged in user:

- In EL: `#{request.remoteUser}`
- Using JSF API: `FacesContext.getCurrentInstance().getExternalContext().getRemoteUser();`
- From HttpServletRequest: `getUserPrincipal()` and `getRemoteUser()`
- Using injection: `@Inject Principal principal;`

Comment: Okay, obviously i didn't make myself clear enough: I don't want the user to have to sign in to my app, i want to user single-sign-on and therefore get the username of the user, who is currently logged on on teh client pc (Needs to work for Windows only). I updated my questio to make that more clear

Comment: I don't think there is any "standard-solution" in the Java EE space for this - remember, Java is designed to be platform independent. If you do find a way, please let me know however, I'd be quite surprised if you can do that at all.