# How to post java website on IIS running on glassfish V3 application server

Tags: jakarta-ee, iis-6, glassfish-3, web-deployment

I am using glassfish v3 application server for my java website. I wanted the remote user login name from that website. i tried all the possible ways but i didn't got the solution for that i posted my question which is 
[How to get the remote user's username in java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25031746/how-to-get-the-remote-users-username-in-java)
Then i thought i can post my website on IIS so that i can get the remote user login name using anonymous login. i Tried creating a virtual directory but it was throwing class not found exception.

Please tell me how can i post my website running on glassfish v3 server on IIS v6.

Comment: Guys Please spare some time to answer this question.

Comment: Guys Help me on this, or tell me any other feasible solution for this.