# How to fetch a home directory or user name of a remote system

Tags: java, remote-access

I know that I can get the local user name and home directory by the command

> System.getProperty("user.name")

and

> System.getProperty("user.home")

I would like to know if there are any commands available in java to obtain a remote system's user name and home directory.

Comment: @meditat no,he is under a different IP

Comment: define "a remote system", what kind of access do you have?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to get the remote user's username in java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25031746/how-to-get-the-remote-users-username-in-java)